# I'm trying to retrieve a file that is stored in internal storage on an Android device but I can't find it

Tags: android, file, directory

I have written a file to internal storage. It shows up in my "data/data/package-name/file folder. It exists when I check in this directory. But in the code below, when I type File file = new File(fileName), file.exists() comes up false. Can anyone tell me why?

```
fileName = "match." + mMatchID + ".json";

Log.d(TAG1, "Filename: " + fileName);   // the file name is ok


File file = new File(fileName);

Log.d(TAG1, "Does File Exist: " + file.exists());

Gson gson = new Gson();


if (file.exists()) {
    // read file into memory and assign the string to matchString
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        matchString = reader.readLine();

        Log.d(TAG1, "When you read the match back into memory: " + matchString);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Log.d(TAG1, "an error occured:" );
    } finally{
        try {
            assert reader != null;
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    match = gson.fromJson(matchString, Match.class);
}


match.setMatchName(mMatchNameEditText.getText().toString());
match.setMatchLevel(mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

// convert match back to JSON
matchString = new Gson().toJson(match);

FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
    fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(matchString.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        assert fos != null;
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Toast.makeText(EditMatchActivity.this, "Match Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_GLOBAL_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH_NAME, mMatchNameEditText.getText().toString());
String level = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
editor.putString(CURRENT_MATCH_LEVEL, level);
editor.apply();
```

Here is the evidence in the stack trace:

```
08-22 14:17:50.674 2883-2883/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/EditMatchActivity: Filename: match.08222017PGA5614023.json
08-22 14:17:50.674 2883-2883/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/EditMatchActivity: Does File Exist: false
08-22 14:17:50.703 2883-3109/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f92842e1d20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f92842c2f00)
08-22 14:17:50.710 2883-3109/com.checkinsystems.ez_score D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f92842e1d20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f92842c2f00)
08-22 14:17:52.684 2883-3109/com.checkinsystems.ez_score E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f92842e25e0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"match." + mMatchID + ".json"` is a simple filename. It is not a fully-qualified path to a file.

You need to check a `File` using code that matches how you created that file in the first place. If you used `getFilesDir()` or `openInputStream()` to create that file, then use `new File(getFilesDir(), "match." + mMatchID + ".json")` to create the corresponding `File`.

Comment: Thanks. That solved one problem but I may have a similar one. This couple of lines is now throwing an error:     reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                            matchString = reader.readLine();
                            Log.d(TAG1, "When you read the match back into memory: " + matchString);   The first fix you gave me worked. I found the file, but this line of code is saying there is no such file or directory

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid: Well, again, you need to use the fully-qualified path to the file. Your `FileReader` needs to be passed the `File` shown in my answer.

Comment: When I tried FileReader(getFilesDir(), fileName) it didn't work. It threw an error. But when I passed the File object to the FileReader it did work. That's strange. When you look up the documentation it says I can pass a file name or a file object to the FileReader but in this case it only worked when I passed the file object. There must be something I'm missing here. At least it's working. Thanks for the help. Still I wish I understood why this makes a difference

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid: "When I tried FileReader(getFilesDir(), fileName) it didn't work. It threw an error" -- there is no `FileReader` constructor that takes two parameters. "When you look up the documentation it says I can pass a file name or a file object to the FileReader but in this case it only worked when I passed the file object" -- as I have said twice previously, and once here: **you need to use a fully-qualified path to the file**. A filename is useless on its own.

Comment: Thanks again. I get it now. I guess one of the things that threw me off to was that you don't need the fully qualified path when you create the file. I guess thats  a benefit of the openFileOutput(filename) method. Thanks again. I understand it now :)

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid: "I guess thats a benefit of the openFileOutput(filename) method" -- correct. The counterpart is `openFileInput()`, to get an `InputStream` on what you wrote via `openFileOutput()`. Generally, I recommend being consistent: either use `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()`, or use `getFilesDir()`.